# How to disable "Microsoft recommends different browser settings" notification?

Tags: windows-10, notifications

I get this notification on lower right corner on Windows 10 from time to time:

[image: Microsoft recommends different browser settings notification]

If I click 'Maybe later' button the notification appears again in few days.

I'm not using Edge browser. My search engine in Chrome is set to Google. I suspect that this notification is from Bing Wallpaper app.

Is there a way to disable this notification?

---

**Update:** Some users may see the following dialog instead:

[image: microsoft-edge-recommended-browser-settings]

Comment: What setting is it attempting to have you change? Just the default search engine?

Comment: No idea, I never clicked 'Yes' button.

Comment: So a few questions, are you actually using Edge, when you see this notification?  Have you actually changed the default search from Bing to some other search engine?  When you get this notification are you on Bing by chance?  If so it’s probably a [website notification](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-manage-web-notifications-edge-windows-10#:~:text=How%20to%20customize%20Edge%20notifications%201%20Click%20the,rather%20not%20disable%20all%20of%20them%20completely.%20)

Comment: If it’s NOT a website notification then disabling notifications for [Edge](https://techviral.net/stop-microsoft-edges-pop-up-notifications/) might work. If you can edit your question to include some additional information I would appreciate it

Comment: I updated my question, thank you! I'm not using Edge browser. My search engine in Chrome is set to Google. I suspect that this notification is from Bing Wallpaper app

Comment: Yes; I would agree that the notification is being generated by the application, so disabling notifications for that application, seems to be the simplest answer. Have you tried that?

Comment: You might also just remove the extension from Chrome, looks like you would have to silence notifications for chrome entirely, to accomplish your goal.

Comment: I have Edge set as my default browser and Bing as the default search engine, and I got this today. I found it very confusing.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to disable this notification?

This feature was added with the release of Edge 91.

You can disable this notification by doing the following:

1. Navigate to `edge://flags/#edge-show-feature-recommendations` within Microsoft Edge

[image]

2. Set `Show feature and workflow recommendations` to `Disabled` instead of `Enabled` or `Default`
3. Restart Microsoft Edge 91.0.864.37

> I'm not using Microsoft Edge. My search engine in Chrome is set to Google. I suspect that this notification is from Bing Wallpaper app.

Microsoft Edge is still installed by default on all current versions of Windows 10 and can be used by any application that implements a WebView2 .NET control.

Sources:

- [How do I turn off this pop up permanently? Its start getting very annoying.](https://www.reddit.com/r/MicrosoftEdge/comments/no7csf/how_do_i_turn_off_this_pop_up_permanently_its/)
- [How to disable Microsoft Edge's annoying Bing recommendation alerts](https://www.neowin.net/news/how-to-disable-microsoft-edges-annoying-bing-recommendation-alerts/)

Comment: Worth pointing out that this flag is an experimental feature and there was likely a bug in its implementation.  It was likely only supposed to only display the notification once.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to go to "Windows Settings", search for notifications and turn off the notifications from Bing? I know its a very simple solucion and you maybe already tried it.