# How do I block this MS Edge pop-up dialog on browser close?

Tags: windows, windows-10, browser, microsoft-edge, popups

Microsoft Edge of late has begun repeatedly showing me this pop-up dialog almost every time I try to close its window after a browsing session (cannot predict or figure out what causes it *not* to show up *sometimes*):

[image: Edge_Irritating_Popup_on_Close]

How do I block it for good *without* pinning those sites? (Assuming it'll stop bugging me if I do, which is not guaranteed.) I haven't found any Experimental Flags related to this 'feature' yet.

Edge is updated to the latest *Version 115.0.1901.188 (Official build) (64-bit)*, running on *Windows 10 x64 22H2 (build 19045.3208)*.

Comment: that has to be annoying - none of my 4 computers do that

Comment: Does not happen here. Try Repairing the Edge browser.  Try running DISM / SFC:  (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: I don't see anything like that either. I assume more people have that since there are 3 upvotes. Perhaps it's some extension? Which ones do you have enabled? Does it happen in incognito mode? Also, you sure this is Windows 10, which is in tags? Looks more like 11, unless it's some weird theme.

Comment: @JaromandaX: You're lucky (so far)! Microsoft, like many other tech companies, is known to roll out certain features gradually, or even do A-B testing of new 'features' with sections of its user-base. Unfortunately it looks like I'm one of the 'chosen ones' in this case.

Comment: @John: Thank you, but it's got absolutely nothing to do with system or browser corruption (and I really don't like sfc/dism/reinstall etc. suggested as a panacea for all Windows ills). Just for the record though, both sfc and dism outputs indicate no issues whatsoever, as expected. I know how to administer and maintain my systems, far better than most.

Comment: @Destroy666: See my response to JaromandaX above re. why you may not have encountered this (yet). Only 1 extension: uBlock Origin. Actually tried a browser reset, & as expected, even on bare bones Edge the popup showed up on close soon enough (thankfully, since browsing sans uBlock is hell). Not sure I've ever seen it while closing an Incognito Mode Edge window, since I hardly use that (Edge isn't my primary browser). Finally, I know what OS I use. The screenshot shows only the popup dialog cropped, and yes, that's what it looks like in Edge on Win10 22H2 (build 19045.3208). No OS/Edge themes.

Comment: [If it's the flag I think it is, that flag has been around for about 3 years now, in some way or another.](https://superuser.com/questions/1652058/how-to-disable-microsoft-recommends-different-browser-settings-notification)

Answer (score 8):

Try:

- Type `edge://flags` in the address bar and press enter
- Type `Show feature and workflow recommendations` in the search bar on top
- Click on the dropdown menu beside the option and select Disable
- Restart Edge

As a shortcut, you can type `edge://flags/#edge-show-feature-recommendations` in the address bar and press enter